# Target only one element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this little problem with my code, and I though guys at Stack Overflow might know how to solve this.

So here's the scenario:

I need to append `strong` inside `p` into another element which will be post caption. I have been able to create solution this, but I'm having problem. Photo caption duplicates into other same named elements, which I don't want to happen. So post may have photo caption, but not always, but it still needs to work.

HTML

```
<div class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare erat sit amet nulla  faucibus pharetra. Donec in mauris lorem. Pellentesque egestas aliquet lobortis. Praesent molestie.</p>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare erat sit amet nulla faucibus pharetra. Donec in mauris lorem. Pellentesque egestas aliquet lobortis. Praesent molestie.</p>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare erat sit amet nulla faucibus pharetra. Donec in mauris lorem. Pellentesque egestas aliquet lobortis. Praesent molestie.</p>
  <p><strong>This is a caption.</strong></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $caption = $(".post strong:first-child").text();
var $removable = $(".post strong:first-child");

$(".post strong:first-child").parent().remove();
$removable.remove();

$(".post").append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");
```

Here's Codepen snippet:

http://codepen.io/aleksitappura/pen/auvrE

I'll appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Can you append your question with the actual code you tried? It's helpful to see the Codepen but not useful in case the codepen link dies for future users.

Comment: Can you please move your code into the question itself? SO tries to not rely on outside resources.

Comment: What is your goal? Your code is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.

Comment: @user3558931 Nope. It duplicates it into every div that has same name, not just there, where it has original 'strong' element.

Comment: If you save a reference to the `source`, then you would be able to return the new content only to that `.post`. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple `strong` tags, you can try this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/7mP8Y/1/

JS:

```
var i = $(".post strong:first-child");
i.each(function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    var post = elem.parents('.post:first');
    var $caption = elem.text();
    elem.parent().remove();
    post.append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, put if I put another caption in other post it duplicates like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7mP8Y/ I would appreciate if you know any solution to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/U6Qd3/)

You need to save a reference to the `source` so that you can return  the caption there:

```
var $caption = $(".post strong:first-child").text();
var $removable = $(".post strong:first-child");
//SAVE A REFERENCE TO THE SOURCE/TARGET
var $source = $removable.closest('.post');

$(".post strong:first-child").parent().remove();
$removable.remove();
//ADD TO SOURCE/TARGET
$source.append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");
```

[**UPDATE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/U6Qd3/3/)

In case you're targeting more than one element, you can use `.each` as follows and each element will be changed on it's own:

```
$(".post strong:first-child").each(function() {
    var $caption = $(this).text();
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.post');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $parent.append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems like if I put another caption in other post it duplicates like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U6Qd3/1/ Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: That's because more than one element meet your original select and you may have to use `.first()` ... `.eq(1)` .. etc depending on which one is your target as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/U6Qd3/2/ -------> `var $removable = $(".post strong:first-child").first();`

Comment: Mmm, that may be causing a trouble because I'm using to implement this to Tumblr, and you never know which one of posts it will be. Any solution to make it current function only in div that caption is?

Answer (score 0):

`$(".post strong:first-child").parent().remove();` indicates the first `strong` in each `.post`.

If you only wanted the first `.post` you'd do `$('.post').first().find('strong');` or `$('.post:first-child strong');`

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery code like below.

```
 var $caption = $(".post strong:first-child").text();
 var $removable = $(".post strong:first-child");

 $(".post strong:first-child").parent().append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");

 $removable.remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hbdkD)

**EDIT**

If you want to do this for all the post section then you have to use `each` function like below.

```
 $(".post").each(function(){  
 var $caption = $(this).find("strong:first-child").text();
 $(this).find("strong:first-child").parent().append("<p class='post-caption'>" + $caption + "</p>");
 $(this).find("strong:first-child").remove();
 });
```

[**DEMO2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akjno)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work like expected. If I put another caption in other post, they print in same caption like this: http://codepen.io/aleksitappura/pen/ailbH. Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: Updated my solution. Check it out.